# Экранированные кавычки в JavaScript + dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Пишу код на python + обработка событий на сайте javascript. Возникла необходимость послать запрос с кавычками. Кавычки я заэкранировала слэшем:

```html
 var field_td = dojo.create("td");
field_td.innerHTML = "<span id='crfield' contenteditable='false' ondblclick = 'clickTree(activeControl, \'" + response.res[j] + "\')' class='table_list'>" + response.res[j] + "</span>";
```

но возникла ошибка: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
Я долго искала подвох, и оказалось, что экранированные слэшем кавычки нужно заменить на двойные (") и код заработает. Почему?

Upd. Проблема в том, что для корректного запроса мне там нужны именно одинарные кавычки, потому что в базе данных поля обычно замыкаются двойными.

Проблема решена, большое спасибо Grundy!

```
var field_td = dojo.create("td");
var span = document.createElement('span');
   span.id = 'crfield';
   span.contenteditable = 'false';
   span.ondblclick = function(){
       clickTree(activeControl, response.res[j]);
   };
   span.className = 'table_list';
   span.innerHTML =  response.res[j];
field_td.appendChild(span);
```

Тот же код можно написать с помощью метода dojo.create вместо document.createElement.

Comment: приведенный код - это яваскрипт? он рабочий или в нем описанная ошибка возникает?

Comment: думаю потому, что ваши экранированные одинарные идут после одинарных, а надо чередовать. типа так: `" ' \" \' foo \' \" ' "`

Comment: вот поэтому лучше не строку собирать, а сразу элементы создавать

Comment: Код - javascript, он превращается в рабочий, если заменить экранированные кавычки в двойные (") в двух местах. Мне казалось, из вопроса понятно, простите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема при сборе строки html с атрибутами - расстановка и экранирование кавычек.

Чтобы узнать почему "не сработало" экранирование в данном случае, стоит просто посмотреть полученную строку.

```
"<span id='crfield' contenteditable='false' ondblclick = 'clickTree(activeControl, \'" + response.res[j] + "\')' class='table_list'>" + response.res[j] + "</span>";
```

Пускай значением `response.res[j]` будет `test`, тогда получим строку

```
<span id='crfield' contenteditable='false' ondblclick = 'clickTree(activeControl, 'test')' class='table_list'>test</span>
```

Как видно из результата имеем одинаковые кавычки в атрибуте `ondblclick`.

Что тут произошло?
Кавычки экранировались, но, они экранировались для собираемой строки.

Таким образом решением проблемы может стать замена кавычек на двойные ("), <strike>либо экранирование с расчетом, что результирующая строка будет также обрабатываться</strike>

```
"<span id='crfield' contenteditable='false' ondblclick = 'clickTree(activeControl, \\'" + response.res[j] + "\\')' class='table_list'>" + response.res[j] + "</span>";
```

В итоге получим

```
<span id='crfield' contenteditable='false' ondblclick = 'clickTree(activeControl, \'test\')' class='table_list'>test</span>
```

и как видно теперь в строке для атрибута `ondblclick` одинарные кавычки также экранированы.

Двойное экранирование не помогло, зато поможет замена кавычек на спец символы html, например, для одинарной кавычки - `&#39;`

```
"<span id='crfield' contenteditable='false' ondblclick = 'clickTree(activeControl, &#39;" + response.res[j] + "&#39;)' class='table_list'>" + response.res[j] + "</span>";
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
var response = {
    res: {
      0: 'test'
    }
  },
  j = 0;

document.body.innerHTML = "<span id='crfield' contenteditable='false' ondblclick = 'clickTree(activeControl, &#39;" + response.res[j] + "&#39;)' class='table_list'>" + response.res[j] + "</span>";

var activeControl = "Check";

function clickTree(a, b) {
  document.getElementById('crfield').textContent += " " + [a, b];
}
```

Избежать таких проблем с экранированием может помочь работа с объектами, а не строкой, например так

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.id = "crfield";
span.contenteditable = false;
span.ondblclick = function(){ clickTree(activeControl, response.res[j]);};
span.className = "table_list";

field_td.appendChild(span);
```

Пример:

```js
var response = {
    res: {
      0: 'test'
    }
  },
  j = 0;


var span = document.createElement('span');
span.id = "crfield";
span.contenteditable = false;
span.textContent = response.res[j];
span.ondblclick = function() {
  clickTree(activeControl, response.res[j]);
};
span.className = "table_list";

document.body.appendChild(span);

var activeControl = "Check";

function clickTree(a, b) {
  document.getElementById('crfield').textContent += " " + [a, b];
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, с двойным экранированием не получилось: в событии _ondblclick_ выходит ересь какая-то, к примеру:

<span id="crfield" contenteditable="false" ondblclick="clickTree(activeControl, \" ЗАО="" "Рога и копыта"\')'="" class="table_list">ЗАО "Рога и копыта"</span>

Comment: @NewDevelop, лучше добавляйте код, непосредственно в вопрос, в комментариях он нечитаем. В идеале, нужно чтобы вы сделали пример в сниппете тут или на jsfiddle который бы повторил вашу ошибку

Comment: Если создавать объект span, ошибка пропадает, но событие _ondblclick_ не выполняется. Привела Ваш код к такому виду:

var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.id = 'crfield';
    span.contenteditable = 'false';
    span.ondblclick = function(){clickTree(activeControl, response.res[j])};
    span.className = 'table_list';
field_td.innerHTML = "<span " + span + ">"+ response.res[j] +"</span>";

Comment: @NewDevelop, я повторюсь: в комментариях код _абсолютно нечитаем_

Comment: Хорошо, я постараюсь добавить пример в пост.

Comment: @NewDevelop, да, попробовал двойное экранирование - действительно не работает в html :-)

Comment: @NewDevelop, добавил рабочие примеры в ответ

Comment: Спасибо за предложенное решение, оно работает, только нужно определить innerHTML объекта span. Добавила рабочий код в пост.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае решение с созданием элемента span сработает, но в моём случае - в цикле - в метод ondblclick в качестве аргумента response.res[j] всегда передаётся последнее значение. Поэтому я вернулась к первоначальному варианту и доработала его с помощью предложенного @Grundy двойного слэша:

```
var val = response.res[j].toString().replace(new RegExp('"','g'),'\\"');
newRow.innerHTML = "<span id='crfield' contenteditable='false' ondblclick = 'clickTree(activeControl, &quot;"+ val + "&quot;)' class='table_list'>" + response.res[j] + "</span>";
```

Код заработал корректно!

Comment: проблема с циклом решается замыканием, посмотри вопросы про замыкания тут :)